# An action for an already "settled" promise will occur only after the stack has cleared and a clock-tick has passed

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

> An action can be assigned to an already "settled" promise. In that case, the action (if appropriate) will be performed at the first asynchronous opportunity. Note that promises are guaranteed to be asynchronous. Therefore, an action for an already "settled" promise will occur only after the stack has cleared and a clock-tick has passed. The effect is much like that of setTimeout(action,10).

```
const promiseA = new Promise( (resolutionFunc,rejectionFunc) => {
    resolutionFunc(777);
});
// At this point, "promiseA" is already settled.
promiseA.then( (val) => console.log("asynchronous logging has val:",val) );
console.log("immediate logging");

// produces output in this order:
// immediate logging
// asynchronous logging has val: 777
```

What do they mean by: **An action for an already "settled" promise will occur only after the stack has cleared and a clock-tick has passed**?

If `promiseA.then( (val) => console.log("asynchronous logging has val:",val) );` statement shows output after `console.log("immediate logging");`, does it mean that that statement has already been sent for execution but it producing the result in an asynchronous manner?

Comment: No, it means that the whole of `.then()` happens after `console.log("immediate logging");`. If the execution was already scheduled but "postponed" then `a = 1; Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(a)); a = 2;` would only print `1` but that's not the case

Comment: @VLAZ Please explain: `No, it means that the whole of .then() happens after console.log("immediate logging");` Why would this happen? Write an answer, please.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*sent for execution*"? What is your mental model of the event loop?

Comment: It would happen because that's how the spec was defined.

Comment: read https://promisesaplus.com/ ... it explains *onFulfilled or onRejected must not be called until the execution context stack contains only platform code.* - which is further explained *Here “platform code” means engine, environment, and promise implementation code. In practice, this requirement ensures that onFulfilled and onRejected execute asynchronously, after the event loop turn in which then is called, and with a fresh stack. can be implemented with either a “macro-task” such as setTimeout or setImmediate, or with a “micro-task” mechanism such as MutationObserver or process.nextTick.*

Comment: @VLAZ "*the whole of `.then()`*" is misleading. The whole *callback* passed to `.then(…)`, yes.

Comment: @Bergi I agree, I didn't express myself clearly enough. It's the callback itself, not the `.then` call.